# Apache Camel's Aggregator2 to aggregate XML documents into a single huge document

Tags: apache-camel

Is that possible to aggregate multiple small XML documents:

```
<doc><field name="XXX">fieldValue</field><doc>
```

using aggregator2 (camel 2.7.0) into one big document

```
<result><doc>...</doc><doc>...</doc><doc>...</doc>...<doc>...</doc></result>
```

without using some custom aggregator processor? I've managed to get it done creating custom aggregator, but now I'm simplifying my code, so would like to get rid of it if camel supports that out of the box.

My custom aggregator looks like:

```
class DocsAggregator implements Processor {
  void process(Exchange exchange) {

    def builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
    def Document parentDoc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream("<?xml version='1.0'?><add></add>".toString().bytes));
    def groupedExchanges = exchange.properties.find {it.key == 'CamelGroupedExchange'}

    groupedExchanges.value.each { Exchange x ->
    def Document document = x.'in'.body

    def bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(bos))
    def node = document.documentElement.childNodes.find { Node it -> it.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE}
    def cloned = parentDoc.adoptNode(node)
    parentDoc.documentElement.appendChild(cloned)
   }
   exchange.in.body = parentDoc
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so you are using grouped exchange option. Then its a bit different. The data is stored as a property on the exchange as a list.

Instead of the processor you can use a POJO and bind a parameter to the property. But the List still contains Exchange objects so you need to invoke the getIn().getBody() methods on it. But if you do it like this you don't need to import any Camel API in the POJO.

```
public Document mergeMyStuff(@Property("CamelGroupedExchange") List grouped) {

    Document parent = ...
    for (int i = 0; i < grouped.size; i++) {
        Document doc = list.get(i).getIn().getBody(Documemt.class);
        .. add to parent doc
    }

    return parent;
}
```

Comment: I've been using this as a guideline for my own (first) attempt at aggregating XML documents. Unfortunately, it seems like the TypeConverter doesn't want to convert my XML, returning a null object instead. Changing the type to `String.class` does print the full document.

Answer (score 1):

By custom aggregator processor, you mean a custom AggregationStrategy? If that's the case, then no. Currently that's required.

We have on the roadmap to offer a pojo model for the aggregation so you dont need to use that Camel API. So expect this to be simpler in the future.

Comment: No my custom aggregator is a simple processor receiving grouped exchanges. Edited my post putting the code sample there.